# Linq Queries with multiple group by and Scalar valued function

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to write a LINQ query, having multiple group by and scalar valued functions using Entity Framework.

This is a sample query with simpler names:

```
var test = context.<db_view>.Where(predicate)
                            .GroupBy(x => new {x.col1, x.col2, x.col3})
                            .Select(y => new
                                         {
                                             a = y.key.col1,
                                             b = y.key.col2,
                                             c = y.key.col3,
                                             d = ctx.ScalarFunction(y.key.col2)
                                         });
```

I however get an error:

```
"Column Distinct1.col1 is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."
```

I do have col1 in the GROUP BY Clause. Am I missing something here?

This is the SQL Query generated by Entity Framework:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS [C1], 
    [Distinct1].[col1] AS [col1], 
    [Distinct1].[col2] AS [col2], 
    [Distinct1].[col3] AS [col3], 
    [dbo].[scalarfunction]([Distinct1].[col2]) AS [C2], 
    FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Extent1].[col1] AS [col1], 
        [Extent1].[col2] AS [col2], 
        [Extent1].[col3] AS [col3], 
        FROM (SELECT 
    [view].[col1] AS [col1], 
    [view].[col2] AS [col2], 
    [view].[col3] AS [col3], 
    [view].[col4] AS [col4], 
    [view].[col5] AS [col5], 
    [view].[col6] AS [col6] 

    FROM [dbo].[view] AS [view]) AS [Extent1]
        WHERE (predicate
    )  AS [Distinct1]
```

Comment: Can you show SQL query which is generated by entity framework?

Comment: I have added the SQL to the question.

Comment: What happens when you try to run that SQL directly using management studio?

Answer (score 0):

Why use `GroupBy`? You don't need groups. You just need (col1, col2 col3) distinct tuples.
So use the `Distinct` operator.
Try this:

```
var test = context.<db_view>.Where(predicate)
                        .Select(x => new {x.col1, x.col2, x.col3})
                        .Distinct()
                        .Select(y => new
                                     {
                                         a = y.col1,
                                         b = y.col2,
                                         c = y.col3,
                                         d = ctx.ScalarFunction(y.col2)
                                     });
```